# how to translate entry form fields to other language in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

iam using asp.net mvc, i want to translate my entry form fields which user entered into other language to display.By using localization i can able to get only the default words which i have set.

Here is the code for localization which i used to store

```
       public ActionResult Index()

    {
             ViewData["Message"] = Resources.Global.Message;
return View();
     }
```

And in the view am calling

```
@ViewData["Message"];
```

Here i stored the language data in  resource file

But i want to translate the user entered data.Is there any other option to do

Comment: No, the user will have to type their input in each language. What specific part are you having trouble with, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,if user creates entry data in english, i want to show it in arabic language in index list.

Comment: Do you mean you want your program to automatically translate input from English to Arabic?